# FullCalendar doesn't display the proper time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, fullcalendar

I have looked at all the examples and I can't figure out why FullCalendar won't show the proper time for my events. For each event it just lists 12a instead of the actual time. Can someone please take a look at my code below and let me know what I am doing wrong.

JavaScript

```
  jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        allDayDefault: false,           
           disableDragging: true,
            eventSources: [{
             events: function(start, end, callback) {
                     var month = end.getMonth();
                     month = ('0' +month).slice(-2)
                     if(month == '0')
                     {
                     var year = start.getFullYear(); month = '12';
                     }
                     else
                     var year = end.getFullYear();

                    var new_url = "<?php echo get_bloginfo('siteurl').'/json-events.php?month='; ?>" + month + "&year="+year;

                    if( new_url != current_url ){

                        jQuery.ajax({
                            url: new_url,
                            dataType: 'json',
                            type: 'POST',
                            success: function( response ) {

                                current_url = new_url;
                                user_events = response;

                                callback(response);

                            }
                        });
                   }else{
                       callback(user_events);
                   }
            }

            }],
            theme: true,
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next',
                center: 'title',
                right: '' 
            },
        editable: true,
         eventRender: function(event, element) {

    element.qtip({
        content: event.description
    });
},
```

.

PHP

```
require_once("includes/classService.php");
$classService = new MBClassService();

require_once("includes/clientService.php");
$classClient = new MBClientService(); 

session_start();    

function cmp($a, $b) {
        $expA = explode('T',$a->StartDateTime);
        $startTimesA  = strtotime($expA[1]).'  ';
        $expB = explode('T',$b->StartDateTime);
        $startTimesB  = strtotime($expB[1]);  
    return (strcmp ($startTimesA,$startTimesB)); 
}

$time = '';

$currentYr = $_GET['year'];

$currentDy = '01';

$currentMonth = $_GET['month'];

$k = 0;  

    $startDate = $currentYr.'-'.$currentMonth.'-'.$currentDy;
    $lastDay = date('t',strtotime($startDate));
    $endofDate =  $currentYr.'-'.$currentMonth.'-'.$lastDay;
    $recordOfClientAddClass = $classClient->GetClientSchedule($_SESSION['ClientId'],$startDate,$endofDate);
    $bookClassArray = array();

for($k = 0; $k < count($recordOfClientAddClass); $k++) {
    $bookClassArray[] = $recordOfClientAddClass[$k]->ClassID;
}

for( $j = 1; $j <= $lastDay; $j++ ) { 
    $days = sprintf("%02s", $j);
    $months = sprintf("%02s", $currentMonth);
    $currentYr = date('Y');
    $start =  $currentYr.'-'.$months.'-'.$days.' 00:00:00';
    $ends =  $currentYr.'-'.$months.'-'.$days.' 23:59:59';
    $classesList = $classService->GetClasses(array(), array(), array(), array(), $ends, $ends);
    //echo "<pre>"; print_r($classesList);

    if(!empty($classesList[0])) {

        uasort($classesList, 'cmp');

        $classesList = array_values($classesList);

        for($k = 0; $k < count($classesList); $k++ ) {
            $exp = explode('T',$classesList[$k]->StartDateTime);
            $startDateOfClass = $exp[0];
            $startTime  = $exp[1];
            $reformatted_stime = date('g:i a',strtotime($startTime));
            $endTime = end(explode('T',$classesList[$k]->EndDateTime));
            $t1 = strtotime($startTime);
            $t2 = strtotime($endTime);
            $delta_T = ($t2 - $t1);
            $hours = round((($delta_T % 604800) % 86400) / 3600, 2); 
            $minutes = round(((($delta_T % 604800) % 86400) % 3600) / 60, 2); 
            $seconds = round((((($delta_T % 604800) % 86400) % 3600) % 60), 2);
            if($hours)
                $time .= $hours ." hour "  ;
            if($minutes)
                $time .= $minutes ." Minutes " ;
            if($seconds)
                $time .= $seconds ." Second "  ; 
        $reformatted_etime = date('g:i a',strtotime($endTime)); 

        if(time() < strtotime($startDateOfClass) && !in_array($classesList[$k]->ID,$bookClassArray))
            $url = $classesList[$k]->ID."&".$startDateOfClass."";
        else
            $url = "";

        if(in_array($classesList[$k]->ID,$bookClassArray))
            $register = "Already Registered!";
        else
            $register = "";

        $description = '';
        if($register != "")
            $description  .= '<strong style="color:#64C063;">'.$register.'</strong><br>';
        $description  .= '<strong>Class Name:</strong> '.$classesList[$k]->ClassDescription->Name.'<br> <strong>Teacher:</strong> '.$classesList[$k]->Staff->Name.'<br> <strong>Duration:</strong> '.$time.

              '<br> <strong>Time:</strong> '.$reformatted_stime.' To ' .$reformatted_etime."";

        if($url) {
            $jsonFirstArry[] = array(
                'title' => $classesList[$k]->ClassDescription->Name,
                'start' => "$currentYr-$months-$days",
                'url' => $url,
                'className' => 'clickTip',
                'description' => "$description"
            );
        } else {
            $jsonFirstArry[] = array(
                'title' => $classesList[$k]->ClassDescription->Name,
                'start' => "$currentYr-$months-$days",
                'className' => 'clickTip',
                'description' => "$description"
            );
        }

        $time = '';

        }
    }
}
echo  json_encode($jsonFirstArry); 
?>
```

.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That's the default time format for FullCalendar. You'll want to look at the [timeFormat documentation](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/text/timeFormat/) for details on how to implement a change to it, and the [formatDate documentation](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/utilities/formatDate/) for specifics on how the time formats work.

As both an example and a quick fix to your specific problem, if you were to specify...

```
timeFormat: 'h:mmtt'
```

...in your calendar object, at the same level where you specify your event sources and theme, that should display the full "am" or "pm". Under this formatting, 7pm would display "7:00pm".

Comment: I understand the format but I can't seem to find what parameter I'm not setting to change the default time.

Comment: Ah, sorry. Answering the wrong question. Have you checked the JSON output of your PHP? It seems more plausible that your service is producing the wrong times than the calendar is making them up.